# How to keep data size to minimum in postgresql table?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I recently deployed a flask-postgresql based app on heroku, I am quite surprised that with just 1 row of data in table the data size is 7.3 as shown in the postgresql database dashboard on heroku.

```
::DATABASE=> \d messages;
                                      Table "public.messages"
  Column  |            Type             |                         Modifiers                         
----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 msg_id   | integer                     | not null default nextval('messages_msg_id_seq'::regclass)
 fullName | character varying(60)       | 
 message  | character varying           | 
 ip       | character varying(20)       | 
 done     | boolean                     | 
 pub_date | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "messages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (msg_id)
```

Comment: In Heroku, the dashboard shows total DB size, not 1 row size. Postgres (as any other system) need some storage for itself also :)

Comment: good to know, it is missleading, probably mentioned in documentation which I didnt read. thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use `psql` meta-commands - modify them a little and you will get the size:

`\dt+ messages` will give you the size of relation

`\l+ database_name` will show the size of database

Comment: what about optimizing each column max size ?

Comment: in most cases - drops into ocean. I would use `text` instead of limited `varchar` at all. try creating two tables, fill em with same data in and check with `pg_total_relation_size` - I bet they wont massively differ